# How do I determine how many odd and even numbers are in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():

    #Open the numbers.txt file
    File=open ('numbers.txt', 'r')

    #This reads the lines in the file
    for line in File:
        #Convert line to float
        amount=float(line)

        #format and display the amount
        print(format(amount,'.2f'))
        print("\n")

    #close the file
    File.close()

    for amount in range (0,13):
        if (amount%2==0):
            print amount


main()
```

This is what the output is suppose to look like:

```
53
15
21
49
8
98
55
21
76
75
53
28

Total of even numbers:[]
Total of odd numbers:[]
```

Comment: might be easier if you show your input

Comment: Using `float` makes it impossible to determine odd/even of course -- that's a concept that only applies to **integer** numbers.

Comment: First I used a loop to read and process numbers.txt, which was a success. Now I am trying to find out how many odd and even numbers are listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you actually have floats in numbers.txt just cast to int:

```
with open("numbers.txt") as f:
    odds = []
    evens = []
    for num in f:
        num = int(num)
        if num % 2: # if there is a remainder num is odd
            odds.append(num) 
        else: # else it must be even
            evens.append(num)

print("All even numbers: {}".format(evens))
print("All odd numbers: {}".format(odds))
print("Total amount of even numbers: {}".format(len(evens))) # len will be total even nums
print("Total amount of odd numbers: {}".format(len(odds)))
```

If you just want the count:

```
with open("numbers.txt") as f:
    odd,even = 0, 0
    for num in f:
        num = int(num)
        if num % 2:
            odd += 1
        else:
            even += 1

print("Total amount of even numbers: {}".format(even))
print("Total amount of odd numbers: {}".format(odd))
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution to the problem worked. I need to review the chapter once more. Thanks again Padraic!

Answer (score 0):

If all numbers are integer (there is no well defined concept of even and odd for floats):

```
import itertools

def odd(i):
    return i % 2

def sumoddevens(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        nums[int(s.strip()) for s in f]
    nums.sort(key=odd)
    results = [0, 0]
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(nums, key=odd):
        results[k] = sum(g)
    return results
```

returns a 2-items list, first the sum of even numbers, then the sum of odd ones.  This works well if the file is not too big to fit in memory; if the file is terribly huge, then:

```
    results = [0, 0]
    with open(fn) as f:
        for s in f:
            i = int(s.strip())
            results[odd(i)] += i
    return results
```

this is slower though more concise, but will work no matter the file size.

Added: some may be surprised at my claim that the latter version "is slower" -- after all it's O(N) while the former has a `sort` thus it's O(N log N).

But, big-O is about "worst case", not *typical* performance.  Python's "timsort" is often preternaturally fast, as it fully exploits any existing "partial sortedness" so common in data from the real world (which this particular `key`, producing only two values, makes more likely); the former version relies on the super optimized internal code for `sort`, `groupby`, and `sum`, while the latter can't.

Sure, at some point (sufficiently huge files) the former version will suffer - but that's quite possibly around the point when sums become so large that `+` isn't `O(1)` any more (summing sufficiently-huge integers is actually `O(log N)` -- think about it!-), and/or around the point where data don't fit comfortably in memory anyway.

So **in practice**, for files that do "fit comfortably in memory", my money in the race would be on the former version, whatever big-O says:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def even_numbers(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
      even_numbers = []
      for line in f:
          line = line.strip()
          if line.isdigit():
              if int(line) % 2 == 0:
                  print(line)

even_numbers('hello.txt')
```